# Consume WCF Json Service with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

Before I start: I'VE READ ALMOST ALL posts about consuming wcf json service with JQuery - no results.

I have wcf json service [LINK](http://www.amder.pl/wcftest.svc/GetPracownicy) which works fine. I can retrive data in my android app, so I assume that WCF's part is not a problem. My script looks like:

```
        function btn() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://amder.pl/wcftest.svc/GetPracownicy",
            type: "GET",
            processData: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            timeout: 10000,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },      
        });
    };
```

It doesn't work. I spent over 2 hours searching solution, tried dozens scripts... Now, I ask you for help, so please spare me comments like "Use google ..." etc.

Here is my Web.config service part:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>    
<services>
  <service name="amder_01.WCFTest">
    <endpoint contract="amder_01.IWCFTest" kind="webHttpEndpoint" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Most of it is based on StackOverflow.

Comment: You are doing a basic HTTP get against a WCF service??? You might as well setup a WebAPI controller in parallel to your WCF (Web API is much simpler and intended for this). You will need to show your bindings if you want help with the WCF side.

Comment: @arche89 Just for your information: jquery will not execute cross domain ajax calls for security reason if you are running script in some other domains or web sites. I am in favour of using Web API to achieve json data.

Comment: I think I will make one dll accessed from both WebApi and WCF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to configure a basic http end point for your wcf service. You need to have something similar to the below in your config file

```
<service name="HelloWorld, IndigoConfig, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
  <endpoint 
      address="/HelloWorld2/"
      contract="HelloWorld, IndigoConfig, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" />
  </endpoint>
</service>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding 
        receiveTimeout="00:00:01"
    />
</bindings>
```